# Open Internet explorer browser from node

Tags: node.js

is it possible to open a particular browser in node js? There is the Open module that opens the default browser but i would like to open IE in certain circumstances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the `open` modules allows you to specify the program:

```
 open("http://nodejs.org", "iexplore");
```

That said, take a look at what `open` is actually doing under the [hood](https://github.com/pwnall/node-open/blob/master/lib/open.js) (assuming Windows)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
exec('start "" "iexplore" "http://nodejs.org"')
```

Comment: i wonder is there a way to refresh the browser once it is opened?